# Send response back through same device for connections coming in through Wireguard

Tags: linux-networking, iproute2, wireguard

I have a server `lanserver` running in my private LAN that is connected to a public server `publicserver` using Wireguard. `publicserver` forwards TCP connections to certain ports to `lanserver` through the Wireguard connection using an iptables `DNAT` rule.

On `lanserver`, Wireguard is set up as a NetworkManager connection. It is routing all internet traffic through Wireguard using `AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0`. This causes the following ip rules to be set up on `lanserver`:

```
[root@lanserver ~]# ip rule show
0:      from all lookup local
31100:  from all lookup main suppress_prefixlength 0
31101:  not from all fwmark 0xcb2e lookup 52014
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
[root@lanserver ~]# ip route show table 52014
default dev wg0 proto static scope link metric 50
```

This setup works properly. An incoming TCP connection to `publicserver` gets forwarded to `lanserver` using the iptables rule. The response is sent back through `publicserver` because the ip rule `31101` matches it.

There is one exception: When I try to open a TCP connection to `publicserver` using IPv6 from my personal computer `pc`, which is also inside my private LAN, it does not work. The problem seems to be that both `pc` and `lanserver` have an IPv6 address in the same public subnet. `publicserver` forwards the connection to `lanserver` successfully, but the response is not routed back through the Wireguard connection but directly to `pc` due to ip rule `31100`.

How can I make sure that all responses for connections coming in through the Wireguard interface on `lanserver` are also sent back through the Wireguard interface, regardless of whether their source IP is in a local subnet?

I can think of solutions in the following directions:

- Disable IPv6 on `lanserver`, causing it to not be on the same subnet as `pc`. Not a very good solution.
- Use `SNAT` on `publicserver` for the port forward. Not an acceptable solution, since some of the services behind the forwarded ports need to know the true source IP.
- Explicitly mention the local IPv6 subnet in the `AllowedIPs` of the Wireguard peer. This does not work because the IPv6 subnet changes every 24 hours.
- Add a custom IP rule that somehow matches all connections coming in through `wg0` and uses the routing table `52014` for them. I'm not sure how exactly to specify such a rule. Also, the problem is that the number of the routing table changes every time the Wireguard connection is restarted. The right place to create such a rule would probably be the `PostUp` script, but NetworkManager does not seem to allow specifying one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting with different options, I decided to stop using NetworkManager and instead use wg-quick directly. On Fedora Server, this was pretty easy and I only had to remove the NetworkManager connection using `nmcli con del wg0` and enable the wg-quick service using `systemctl enable --now wg-quick@wg0` (which reads the config from `/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf`). Switching to wg-quick has the following advantages:

- I can specify custom `PostUp` commands to configure a more complex routing setup
- The number of the Wireguard routing table seems to be constant at `51820`, even though I could not find any documentation about this. This makes it easier to set up custom ip rules.

I then used the `PostUp` command in `wg0.conf` to set up additional ip rules that would make sure that any Wireguard traffic would also respond through Wireguard. There are two options to achieve this:

## Option 1: source IP matching

The ip rules match the Wireguard packages based on their source IP addresses (which is automatically set to the IP address on which the request originally came in):

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.139.192.4/24
Address = fd52:30a4:f9e7:647a::4/64
PostUp  = ip -4 rule add from 10.139.192.4 lookup 51820
PreDown = ip -4 rule del from 10.139.192.4 lookup 51820
PostUp  = ip -6 rule add from fd52:30a4:f9e7:647a::4 lookup 51820
PreDown = ip -6 rule del from fd52:30a4:f9e7:647a::4 lookup 51820
```

## Option 2: fwmark

Some iptables rules are configured to set a `mark` on packages coming in through `wg0`:

```
iptables  -t mangle -A INPUT -j CONNMARK -i wg0 --set-mark 1
ip6tables -t mangle -A INPUT -j CONNMARK -i wg0 --set-mark 1
iptables  -t mangle -A OUTPUT -j CONNMARK -m connmark --mark 1 --restore-mark
ip6tables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -j CONNMARK -m connmark --mark 1 --restore-mark
```

Then this `mark` is matched by the IP rule:

```
PostUp  = ip -4 rule add fwmark 1 lookup 51820
PreDown = ip -4 rule del fwmark 1 lookup 51820
PostUp  = ip -6 rule add fwmark 1 lookup 51820
PreDown = ip -6 rule del fwmark 1 lookup 51820
```

More details about this solution can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/693643/59955).